# ¿Es correcto usar "parón" en lugar de "parada" para las pausas hechas en el fútbol cuando se reúnen las selecciones?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, sinónimos, deportes

En el fútbol cada pocos meses ocurre lo mismo: las competiciones domésticas se detienen unos días para dar paso a partidos de las selecciones nacionales. De un tiempo a esta parte se ha puesto de moda llamar **parón** a esta pausa:

- [*Parón* de selecciones: el Barça pierde a 14 internacionales](http://futbol.as.com/futbol/2015/08/31/primera/1441020029_744279.html)
- [Las 10 razones por las cuales los aficionados odian el *parón* de selecciones](http://www.90min.com/es/posts/1992636-las-10-razones-por-las-cuales-los-aficionados-odian-el-paron-de-selecciones) (la foto que encabeza la noticia no tiene pérdida)
- [El plan de entrenamientos con el *parón* por selecciones](https://www.fcbarcelona.es/futbol/primer-equipo/noticias/2016-2017/el-plan-de-entrenamientos-con-el-paron-por-selecciones)

Me parece curioso que se use esta palabra en lugar de *parada*, así que consulté su significado en el diccionario:

> [**parón**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RxiT61k)
>   1. m. Parada brusca y total de algo o alguien.

Y

> [**parada**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RpRAesx%7CRpSGwPJ)<sup>1</sup>
>   1. f. Acción de parar o detenerse.
>   2. f. Lugar o sitio donde se para.
>   3. f. Fin o término del movimiento de algo, especialmente de la carrera.
>   4. f. Especialmente en la música, suspensión o pausa.
>   5. f. Sitio o lugar donde se recogen o juntan las reses.
>   [mil acepciones más, incluidas unas cuantas militares]

Visto el significado de *parón*, mi duda se acrecienta aún más: si es algo que está más que planificado, no creo preciso llamarlo *brusco*. La parada es total, sí, pero al fin y al cabo solo implica un fin de semana sin fútbol. Llamarlo así me parece algo excesivo.

Se me ocurre que los periodistas de deportes siempre tienden a sobrecargar sus crónicas para darles un toque de épica. Pero, ¿hace falta forzar un adjetivo de esta manera?

¿Alguien sabe por qué, pues, se opta por usar *parón* en lugar de la cálida y bella *parada*? ¿Es correcto?

Comment: Pasa lo mismo con las series: quien sigue la emisión de las series en Estados Unidos sabe que las temporadas sufren de _parones_ en determinados momentos del año.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Que algo sea *[brusco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6BthYKd%7C6BvWbZN%7C6By3fXt)* no quiere decir que sea *inesperado*, tan solo que ha sido rápido o repentino. Una parada puede estar planificada y ser brusca. Por ejemplo, pasar de jugar un partido a la semana a cero a la semana, o emitirse un capítulo de una serie por semana a emitirse cero capítulos. Es como si un coche pasara de cien a cero al chocar contra un muro. Puede estar planificado, como un *crash test*, pero no por ello deja de ser brusco.

En todo caso, según la acepción 4 de *parada*, como argumentas, podría servir para definir la pausa que hacen las temporadas de liga. Sin embargo, yo creo que aquí entran en juego los sentimientos. Para cualquiera que en algún momento haya estado enganchado a la liga o a una serie, ver el siguiente partido o episodio tiene el mismo efecto que recibir tu dosis semanal de droga. la palabra *parada* se puede quedar pequeña, por lo que *parón* describe mejor lo que ha pasado: he dejado de recibir de golpe mi dosis semanal de droga.

Comment: O sea que realmente se toma _brusco_ en su primera acepción, la de _áspero, desapacible_.

Comment: @fedorqui pues no lo había pensado, pero ahora que lo dices, encaja mejor con la sensación de [_mono_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PeswonB|PevMcDo) (acepciones 9 y 10) que produce la parada.